# ImageMagick Right-to-Left text rendering

Tags: imagemagick, right-to-left

ImageMagick does not render Right-to-Left text correctly (it does not join it and its reversed). I need a solution for this...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

ImageMagick uses freetype as it's text-rendering engine, which does not support complex text layout languages. If you need text to image generation for those language, you would need alternative solution.

On Linux/UNIX, Pango has a command line tool called "pango-view", which would output text as PNG. You can then manipulate the PNG with ImageMagick.

On Windows, you can get "pango-view" in cygwin (I believe the dev package for pango in cygwin). If cygwin is unacceptable, you would need to write a program using WCF or GDI+.

Comment: right, I've searched around a bit and found that there is no support for RTL. bump........

Answer (score 0):

Recent versions of ImageMagick supports command line argument `-direction` which [determines rendering direction](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#direction) of the text from Right to Left (`-direction right-to-left`) or Left to Right (`-direction left-to-right`) manner.

See also this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16651123/right-to-left-text-with-imagemagick) for an example.