# Right-To-Left text with ImageMagick

Tags: linux, imagemagick, command-line-interface

I see that newer versions of `imagemagick` [support right-to-left scripts such as Hebrew and Arabic](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php?ImageMagick=6g7kq55da0fv5u2v8b0jdaj225#direction). The fine manual mentions the `direction` flag, but provides no examples of legal arguments. The obvious guesses such as `rtl`, `reverse`, and `right-to-left` are not accepted. What are the legal arguments for the `direction` flag?

```
$ echo "שלום, עולם" | convert -background white -fill black -font Arial -direction reverse -pointsize 20 label:@- hello.png
convert.im6: unrecognized direction type `reverse' @ error/convert.c/ConvertImageCommand/1227. 

$ convert --version
Version: ImageMagick 6.7.7-10 2012-08-17 Q16 http://www.imagemagick.org
Copyright: Copyright (C) 1999-2012 ImageMagick Studio LLC
Features: OpenMP
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The argument should be `right-to-left`. I tried the following command with ImageMagick 6.8.5-7 (on windows) and it worked:

```
convert -background lightblue -fill blue -pointsize 48 -font Arial -direction right-to-left label:"ABCDEFG" A2G_reversed2.png

convert -version
Version: ImageMagick 6.8.5-7 2013-05-19 Q16 http://www.imagemagick.org
Copyright: Copyright (C) 1999-2013 ImageMagick Studio LLC
Features: DPC OpenMP
```

Comment: Thank you. It is still not working on my system, but at least I now know the right syntax.

Comment: Doesn't work.

 magick convert -background black -fill white  -font Arial -direction right-to-left -size 300x300 -pointsize 28  -gravity center  caption:"משחק של דמעות" label.jpg

Generates a black picture with no text. Whereas removing the "-direction" argument makes it work fine.

Answer (score 5):

For Arabic text with ImageMagic, "caption:" and "label:" can be used, with "-direction right-to-left". However, this selects glyphs for standalone characters, not joined-up characters.

The easiest solution seems to be "pango:", where "-direction right-to-left" is not needed.

convert -gravity Center -size 200x200 -fill black -font Arial -pointsize 50 pango:"سلام" arabic_r5.png

OR

convert -gravity Center -size 200x200 -fill black -font Arial -pointsize 50 pango:@utftext.txt arabic_r5.png

[image]

Source: http://multipole.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=26611

Answer (score 4):

The option `-direction right-to-left` will not work for Arabic/Persian. `right-to-left` in ImageMagick won't work for connected-words/glyphed languages like Arabic.

I don't know about other right-to-left languages like Urdu, but I'm sure you might want to **reshape** the text before passing it to ImageMagick. For **Java**([Better-Arabic-Reshaper](https://github.com/agawish/Better-Arabic-Reshaper)), **Python**([arabic_reshaper](https://github.com/mpcabd/python-arabic-reshaper)).